# How to index typed relationships in Solr/Lucene

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, relationship, denormalization

There are two entities which can relate to each other in a typed way. How must I denormalise and index these tables to search in Solr/Lucene for entity A by a specific entity B and relationship type?

For example let's say there are entities `organisation` and `person` linked by the following table:

```
-------------------------------------------
|  link_type | person      | organisation |
-------------+-------------+---------------
|  Founder   | Elon Musk   | SpaceX       |
|------------+-------------+--------------|
|  Chairman  | Elon Musk   | SolarCity    |
|------------+-------------+--------------|
|  Founder   | Lyndon Rive | SolarCity    |
|------------+-------------+--------------|
|  Founder   | Elon Musk   | Tesla        |
-------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to be able to search for all organisations which Elon Musk has founded. The expected document result would be:

```
[SpaceX, Tesla]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions; index each row as a single document, then just query for `link_type:Founder AND person:Elon\ Musk`.

The second option is to use a dynamic, multivalued field with the `link_type` in the name for each organization:

```
link_type_Founder:Elon\ Musk
```

The returned documents are the organizations where the person has the given `link_type`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggested approaches! Is there a major advantage or disadvantage to any solution?

Comment: Unless the number of rows will be an issue I'd go with the first one. It's the least complicated. A common strategy is to also use several collections / cores for the same data set to allow different queries; i.e. you can have two cores with different implementations to answer different queries (where the requirement may differ for faceting or other operations).